# v-model fallthrough attribute on component child not working

Tags: vue.js

I've got a custom `<select>` component:

```html
<!-- Select.vue -->

<template>
  <div class="select" inheritAttrs="false">
    <select v-bind="$attrs">
      <slot></slot>
    </select>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Which I'm using like this

```js
<script>
  import Select from '../components/Select.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      Select
    },
    data() {
      return {
        selection: 'a',
        options: ['a', 'b']
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <Select v-model="selection">
    <option v-for="option in options" :key="options" :value="option">
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </Select>
</template>
```

The `v-model` binding isn't working.

I suspect the binding is being applied to the `<div>` element instead of `<select>`.

I've tried fixing this with `inheritAttrs="false"` and `v-bind="$attrs"` as suggested in the documentation ([fallthrough attributes](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting v-model on a custom component you must declare a prop in the child called `modelValue`.  Then, following the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#component-v-model):

> 1. Bind the `value` attribute of a native `<input>` element to the `modelValue` prop
> 2. When a native `input` event is triggered, emit an `update:modelValue` custom event with the new value

**Select.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="select" inheritAttrs="false">
    <select 
        v-bind="$attrs" 
        :value="modelValue"
        @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
      <slot></slot>
    </select>
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      modelValue: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Besides doing all that, you also had one mistake in your `<option>` v-for where you set `:value="options"`, where `options` is the entire array of values, when it should be `:value="option"` which assigns a single string value.

```js
<option v-for="option in options" :key="options" :value="option">
```

[working Vue playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)